# Model.load: Cannot call method 'hasId' of undefined

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have an application where my model data has the idProperty set to '_id' as per server mongodb data. If I try to load a model instance by given id I get this strange error: Cannot call method 'hasId' of undefined

My model is defined as follows:

```
Ext.define 'heroico.model.Visitor',
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
    fields: [...]
    idProperty: '_id'
    proxy:
        type: 'memory'
```

And I'm just hitting `heroico.model.Visitor.load('FcFaNkhH9TJzQ57D5')` in my chrome console where `FcFaNkhH9TJzQ57D5` is an actual id present in the store. Any ideas?

Extjs version 4.2.1

Comment: what does your field array look like ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get object from store by id, you need to get it FROM STORE!

You need to create store with *model: "heroico.model.Visitor"* and after that do

```
var myVisitor = visitorsStore.getById("your_hard_id")
```

and you get visitor object, based in heroico.model.Visitor model.

If you need to load data from server by static *load* method, you need to set URL in model's proxy config. Sample:

```
Ext.define "heroico.model.Visitort",
  extend: "Ext.data.Model"
  fields: [..]
  idProperty: "_id"
  proxy:
    type: "rest"
    url: "/your/url/for_data_load"
```